# Azure DevOps Artifact Feed giving 500 error in Visual Studio

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I have two packages that build and deploy the artifacts to an organization-level Artifact feed. When I copy the URL from the Connect to Feed button and add the feed to Visual Studio, where I am logged in with my DevOps Azure Account, I receive the following error:

> Could not connect to the package feed Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error - TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: 4071e6a4-bb6a-427d-b3c2-573a28287ec0. (DevOps Activity ID: 4071E6A4-BB6A-427D-B3C2-573A28287EC0)).

The feed does have the public NuGet as an upstream feed. I can't find any logs to determine what the actual error is. My package names are only 18 characters long, and 22 characters long, so I don't believe it is a length issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting the feed and recreating it. After doing that everything started working.